# How many times do I need to cache an ad?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I am fairly new to using Chartboost ads, and haven't managed to find much info regarding this.

I have written a game in which an interstitial ad and 'more apps page' ad is cached immediately when the game loads and is displayed when the user receives a game over message/clicks on show more apps button.

My question is do I have to call `cacheInterstitial()` and `cacheMoreApps()` again every time to cache a new ad whenever a previously cached add is displayed to the user, or is this handled automatically after the first time I call on the api to cache an add?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using Chartboost Autocache feature then YES you will have to call `cacheInterstitial()` and `cacheMoreApps()` again every time you display a previously cached Ad or chartboost will keep on showing same ad again and again.

To use Autocaching feature read the section '[Autocaching](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/204213159#autocache)' in Chartboost docs.